# Create new line in a python string that does NOT effect output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

is it possible to create a new line in a string in one's python code that does NOT effect output?

Like:

```
print "This
is
my
string"
```

But the output when the program is run would just be "This is my string"

Just for purposes of formatting the program in a more readable way for very long strings.

Comment: Use `""" """` or `''' '''` brackets for mutliline strings.

Comment: It would be pretty ugly I think, but you could use a triple quote string, and then trim the newline characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use implicit string joining too:

```
print("this "
      "is "
      "my "
      "string")
```

Comment: This has the advantage that you don't have to start each continuation line at the leftmost column.

Comment: I like it much better than `\ ` continued lines, although I probably use `textwrap.dedent()` and triple-quoted strings more often.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke [explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining), adding a backslash at the end of each line:

```
>>> print "this \
... is \
... my \
... string"
this is my string
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also add a comma after every print statement to print the next output on the same line :

```
print "This",
print "is",
print "my",
print "string"
```